# jQuery UI Resizable irregular snap grid

Tags: jquery-ui

I would like to define an irregular grid for the jQuery UI resizable snap grid

By default I can define a grid of `x` pixel for each column, but I'd like to have something like:

```
0px  200px 250px 300px // note that I've skipped 50, 100 and 150
```

Given this example:
http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/MKgQod

```
    $( "#resizable" ).resizable({
        grid: 50,
        handles: 'e, w'
    });
```

I'd like to make the dragging of the element skip completely the steps where the element becomes red.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, I'm not sure if there's a better way, but this one work as expected:

```
  [style*="width: 50px"],
  [style*="width: 100px"],
  [style*="width: 150px"] {
    width: 200px !important;
  }
```

http://codepen.io/FezVrasta/pen/adoqQm